# Reverse for 'delete_note' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete_note/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django

I am  facing this error while adding this in  my html file

```
<a href="{% url 'delete_note' i.id %}"class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Either `i` or `i.id` is None, probably. Please share view code where `i` is defined (and loop in template also, if `i` is iteration variable).

Comment: can you show your urls.py code

Comment: Nothing can be smelled from your one line code. Instead post your ```delete_note``` function and its ```urls.py``` file.